# Ошибка синтаксиса в pascalABC

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net, syntax

Школьная задача на нахождение количества корней квадратного уравнения. При компиляции выдаёт ошибку синтаксиса **"main.pas(20,9) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "identifier WRITELN" found"**

```
program discriminant;
var a, b, c, disc: integer;
begin
writeln('Эта программа находит колличество корней квадратного уравнения');
writeln('ax^2+bx+c=0');

write('A = ');
readln(a);

write('B = ');
readln(b);

write('C = ');
readln(c);

disc := (b*b)-(4*a*c);

if (disc > 0) then
    writeln('D = ', disc)
    writeln('Два корня')
else if (disc = 0) then
    writeln('D = ', disc)
    writeln('Один корень')
else if (disc < 0) then
    writeln('D = ', disc)
    writeln('Корней нет')
end.
```

Пробовал ставить точки с запятыми в разных вариациях. Не помогло. Как быть?

Comment: *Пробовал ставить точки с запятыми в разных вариациях. Не помогло. Как быть?* А попробуйте в соответствии с требованиями синтаксиса. См. [Условный оператор и оператор выбора](http://pascalabc.net/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0._%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC), пример "Упорядочение двух значений по возрастанию". И обратите внимание на вложенный BEGIN-END.

Comment: @Akina интересно то, что брал я синтаксис написания условных операторов со стороннего сайта и код работал. Стоило мне поставить свои условия, как сразу компилятор выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: @lifono656 вы не условия свои поставили, а дополнительные действия добавили.

Answer (score 1):

Работающий вариант программы. Но это махровый Турбо Паскаль.

```
program discriminant;

var
  a, b, c, disc: integer;

begin
  writeln('Эта программа находит количество корней квадратного уравнения');
  writeln('ax^2+bx+c=0');
  write('A = ');
  readln(a);
  write('B = ');
  readln(b);
  write('C = ');
  readln(c);
  disc := (b * b) - (4 * a * c);
  if (disc > 0) then begin
    writeln('D = ', disc);
    writeln('Два корня')
  end    
  else if (disc = 0) then begin
    writeln('D = ', disc);
    writeln('Один корень')
  end    
  else if (disc < 0) then begin
    writeln('D = ', disc);
    writeln('Корней нет')
  end
end.
```

Ниже - код PascalABC.NET:

```
begin
  Println('Эта программа находит количество корней квадратного уравнения');
  Println('Ax^2+Bx+C=0');
  var (a, b, c) := ReadReal3('введите через пробел A, B, C:');
  var disc := b * b - 4 * a * c;
  Println('D =', disc);
  case Sign(disc) of
  1: Print('Два разных корня');
  0: Print('Два равных корня');
  -1: Print('Действительных корней нет')
  end
end.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `ReadReal3` о_О А по сколько ещё чисел он умеет считывать?

Comment: От 1 до 4. Или сразу массив/последовательность.

Answer (score 0):

Точка с запятой ставится между операторами (statement'ами), но не после последнего. Соответственно перед `else` и `end` точка с запятой не ставится.

Помимо этого нельзя пихать несколько операторов в `if` и `else` - надо их дополнительно оборачивать в `begin` т `end`.

```
if условие then begin
  оператор(1);
  оператор(2);
  оператор(3)
end else ...
```